# Is it possible to customize / change the description content of a fb-share button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is my code, it's from Facebook, it's quite simple:

`<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://www.mysite.com/" data-type="button_count"></div>`

But when I click on the share button, I found that I can't control the description content of the website. Some other sites did but I don't know how they did it.

Is it possible to change it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you add `OG` meta tags?

Comment: @AdamAzad Thanks, is there any place to read a detailed instruction of the `OG` tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook Has complete instruction and the available properties you can add on [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/) site

The basic meta tags are

```
<meta property="og:title" content="{My Title}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="{Site Type}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/og_image.jpg" />
```

And there's more options if you want to add them

Comment: Thanks! I actually added them later but it's still not working. I thought it'd be due to the cache thing so I and a "?nocache" but still not working... Is there anything eles I should try?

Comment: I tried. It's working in the debugger but not ok for the actual case.

Comment: BTW, why I got this -> `fb:admins and fb:app_id tags are missing. These tags are necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high click-through rate.`

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache? can you post your url?

Comment: Here is the page: http://www.mbti123.com/mental/it/ It is in Italian. Thanks for checking :)

Comment: It worked fine with Me, with debugging it and clearing my browser cache :)

Comment: can you see the description showed correctly in Italian in the place? Not English, not the Italian title, but the Italian description? Would you mind sending me a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

no you can't. You control the content with og metatags. If you want to provide a different description, you need to post via app, with the share dialogue: `https://www.facebook.com/dialogue/feed?app_id=APP_ID&link=YOUR_LINK&description=YOUR DESCRIPTION&picture=A_PICTURE_URL&name=SITE TITLE&caption=BEST THINGS EVER` etc etc

Comment: Thanks, but is there any place to read a detailed instruction of the `OG` tags?